# Function for "Next Page" rvest scrape

Tags: r, scrape, rvest

*I've added the final code I used at the bottom in case anyone has a similar question. I used the answer provided below but added a couple of nodes, system sleep time (to prevent being kicked off server), and an if argument to prevent an error after the last valid page is scraped.*

I'm trying to pull several pages from a website using the next page function. I created a dataframe with a nextpage variable and filled in the first value with the starting url.

```
#building dataframe with variables
bframe <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10000))
x <- c("curpage", "nexturl", "posttext")
colnames(bframe) <- x

#assigning first value for nexturl
bframe$nexturl[[1]] <- "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/04/02/canopy-anna-turner/"
```

I want to pull text as follows (I know the code is clunky -- I am brand new at this -- but it does get what I want)

```
##create html object
blogfunc    <-  read_html("http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/04/02/canopy-anna-turner/")
##create object with post content scraped
posttext    <-  blogfunc    %>% 
    html_nodes(".article-content")%>%           
    html_text()                 
posttext    <-  gsub('[\a]', '', blogfunc)
posttext    <-  gsub('[\t]', '', blogfunc)
posttext    <-  gsub('[\n]', '', blogfunc)
##scrape next url
nexturl <-  blogfunc    %>% 
    html_nodes(".prev-post-link-wrap a") %>%    
    html_attr("href")
```

Any suggestions on turning the above into a function and using it to fill in the dataframe? I am struggling to apply online examples.

---

**Working answer with sleep time and if argument for after last valid page.**

````
```{r}
library(rvest)    
url <- "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2008/05/31/the-making-of-a-wet-willy/"
#Select first page.

getPostContent <- function(url){
    Sys.sleep(2)
    #Introduces pauses to convince server not robot.
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_nodes(".article-content")%>%           
        html_text() %>% 
        gsub(x = ., pattern = '[\a\t\n]', replacement = '')
  }
#Pulls node for post content.

getDate <- function(url) {
    Sys.sleep(2.6)
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_node(".updated") %>%
        html_text()
}
#Pulls node for date.

getTitle <- function(url) {
    Sys.sleep(.8)
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_node(".article-title") %>%
        html_text()
    }
#Pulls node for title.

getNextUrl <- function(url) {
    Sys.sleep(.2)
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_node(".prev-post-link-wrap a") %>%
        html_attr("href")
    }
#Pulls node for url to previous post.

scrapeBackMap <- function(url, n){
    Sys.sleep(3)
    purrr::map_df(1:n, ~{
        if(!is.na(url)){
#Only run if URL is not NA
        oUrl <- url
        date <- getDate(url)
        post <- getPostContent(url)
        title <- getTitle(url)
        url <<- getNextUrl(url)

        data.frame(curpage = oUrl, 
                        nexturl = url,
                        posttext = post,
                        pubdate = date,
                        ptitle = title
#prepares functions for dataframe
                        )}
    })
}
   res <- scrapeBackMap(url, 3000)
   class(res)
   str(res)
#creates dataframe
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea I'm following is to scrape each post content, find the 'previous post' url, navigate to that url and repeat the process.

```
library(rvest)    

url <-  "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/04/02/canopy-anna-turner/"
```

#### Scrape post's content

```
getPostContent <- function(url){
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_nodes(".article-content")%>%           
        html_text() %>% 
        gsub(x = ., pattern = '[\a\t\n]', replacement = '')
    }
```

#### Scrape next url

```
getNextUrl <- function(url) {
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_node(".prev-post-link-wrap a") %>%
        html_attr("href")
}
```

Once we have these 'support' function we can glue them together.

#### Apply function `n` times

I guess a `for` loop or `while` may be set to continue until the `getNextUrl` return `NULL`, but I preferred to define a `n` of jump back and apply the function at each 'jump'.

Starting with the original `url` we retrieve its content, then overwrite `url` with the new value extracted and continue until the loop is broken.

```
scrapeBackApply <- function(url, n) {
    sapply(1:n, function(x) {
        r <- getPostContent(url)
        # Overwrite global 'url'
        url <<- getNextUrl(url)
        r
    })
}
```

Alternatively we can use `purrr::map` family and `map_df` in particular to obtain directly a `data.frame` as your `bframe`.

```
scrapeBackMap <- function(url, n) {
    purrr::map_df(1:n, ~{
        oUrl <- url
        post <- getPostContent(url)
        url <<- getNextUrl(url)
        data.frame(curpage = oUrl, 
                        nexturl = url,
                        posttext = post)
    })
}
```

#### Results

```
res <- scrapeBackApply(url, 2)
class(res)
#> [1] "character"
str(res)
#>  chr [1:2] "Six years ago this month, my eldest/oldest/elder/older daughter<U+0085>Okay sidenote <U+0096> the #1 grammar correction I receive on a regula"| __truncated__ ...

res <- scrapeBackMap(url, 4)
class(res)
#> [1] "data.frame"
str(res)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ curpage : chr  "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/04/02/canopy-anna-turner/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/31/a-guest-post-an-snapshop-interview/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/29/explore-il-casey-small-town-big-things/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/27/explore-ok-oklahoma-wondertorium/"
#>  $ nexturl : chr  "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/31/a-guest-post-an-snapshop-interview/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/29/explore-il-casey-small-town-big-things/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/27/explore-ok-oklahoma-wondertorium/" "http://www.ashleyannphotography.com/blog/2017/03/24/the-youngest-cousin/"
#>  $ posttext: chr  "Six years ago this month, my eldest/oldest/elder/older daughter<U+0085>Okay sidenote <U+0096> the #1 grammar correction I receive on a regula"| __truncated__ "Today I am guest posting over on the Bought Beautifully blog about something new my family tried as a way to usher in our Easte"| __truncated__ "A couple of weeks ago, we drove to Illinois to watch one my nieces in a track meet and another niece in her high school musical"| __truncated__ "Often the activities we do as a family tend to cater more towards our older kids than the girls. The girls are always in the mi"| __truncated__
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. This is beautiful and -- as you know -- works perfectly.

Comment: I am running into trouble when I provide an n that goes over the amount of actual pages, which I'd like to do so I don't have to count up the pages. I am using map_df as you suggested.I tried adding an `if(!is.na(url)){_function_}` argument to the getPostContent and getNextUrl functions. I am getting the following: Error in data.frame(curpage = oUrl, nexturl = url, posttext = post: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0).

Comment: To clarify, I tried to run it with `res <- scrapeBackApply(url, 3000)` because I know there are almost 3000 pages I need to grab, but don't know exactly how much.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Adding the code to the bottom of my original post.